# PBS - nodes are free, but they do not start a job

Tags: centos, pbs

I am new administrator of PBS. I downloaded and installed `torque-4.2.6` version. I used default configuration that is provided by torque.setup.

The OS is `CentOS` with `kernel 2.6.18`.

I stopped all the firewall. I confirmed that all the ssh/scp works bi-directionally between server and nodes.

after configuration, everything looks fine. small number of jobs have finished well.

When I submitted 10000 jobs, they finished about 70% of the jobs, but the remainders do not start to work. I found that the server_priv/jobs directory contains the jobs.

I checked the log fines... but I could not find any clue to the problem.

I checked disk space by using `df`, and there is 10% (more than 100GB) of free space and it looks enough to run PBS jobs.

Before I check other things, I ask help to the others in this site.

Comment: As it currently looks this is question is too broad. For one of the "hanging" jobs show what `qstat -f JOBID` prints (replace JOBID with the ID of the job)

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer in spite that my question is too broad. I still do not know why small number of job (for example, 100) is finished normally while large number of job (for example, 10000) is partly finished. For large number of jobs, pbs works fine at early moment but it stops with known reason at later moment. Yesterday, I found that restarting pbs_server and pbs_sched by [pbs_server restart] and [pbs_sched restart] can simply solve the problem. So, I used crontab to execute the restart command periodically in order to solve the problem. Thanks! Je-Hoon Song

Comment: What scheduler are you using?

Comment: It's pbs_sched that is default PBS scheduler. PS. in my previous comment, 'with known reason' should be changed as with unknown reason'. Sorry for mistype. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you attempt to use Maui instead of pbs_sched. While there are a few out there using pbs_sched, most use Maui and its easier to get help using Maui.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. i installed maui and just submitted jobs... i am wondering if this solves the problem. thanks!